# Counter Problems With Buttons

Tags: python-3.x

i am currently trying to make a game in python but have encountered a problem. The idea of the game is to progress through your life and make as much money as possible. The problem i have is that when i click the button to earn money the whole lot just goes crash here are the errors python gives out.

1. raise Empty
   queue.Empty
2. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'function' and 'int'

Now here is my code.

```
import tkinter

Money = 0
Years = 0

def ProgressYears():
      global Years
      Years += 1
      AgeNumber.configure(text=Years)

def Money():
      global Money
      Money += 20
      MoneyNumber.configure(text=Money)



window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("100 Days")
window.geometry('400x400')
window.wm_iconbitmap("100DAYS.ico")
window.configure(background="Light Blue")
#AGE
AgeDisplay = tkinter.Label(text="Age:", bg="Light Blue")
AgeDisplay.pack()

AgeNumber = tkinter.Label(window, text=Years, bg="Light Blue")
AgeNumber.pack()
#MONEY
MoneyDisplay = tkinter.Label(text="Money:", bg="Light Blue")
MoneyDisplay.pack()

MoneyNumber = tkinter.Label(window, text=Money, bg="Light Blue")
MoneyNumber.pack()
#PROGRESS
Progress = tkinter.Button(text="Progress", command=ProgressYears)
Progress.pack()
#WORK
Work = tkinter.Button(text="Earn Money", command=Money)
Work.pack()
```

If someone could troubleshoot it, that would be great

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example. Your code is not runnable on it's own...

Comment: i'm really sorry but i don't know what that means

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have tested it and it has the same problem?

Comment: What have you tested and what has the same problem?

Comment: the code has the same problem

Comment: Which same problem? You are speaking in riddles....

Comment: um the problem that i listed at the start??

Comment: Your problem is too to find anybody to have a look at it. Please provide a shorter example that still exhibits your problem. Please read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: that is as short as i'm going get it and anyway are supposed to be telling me to shorten it or are you supposed to be helping me??

Comment: We are not supposed to do anything. A lot of people will help you if you ask a question that is easily understandable and short enough to understand quickly. Nobody here wants to read and understand your long code (as you might realize by the lack of answers to your question). I was trying to help you create a better question so you will get the answers you are looking for. If you choose to ignore my tips that is your right, but do not expect me to help you any more.

Comment: well i'm sorry but how is that not short enough?it's 40 lines including the spaces and #'s